# Change and Maintain CSS Style of Button State

Tags: css, button

I have 5 list items that act like tabs for a page stored in a Masterpage in a asp.net application. When the user selects a list item, I would like to redirect the the page, and change the class for that list item (tab) to show the active tab the user is on.  What is the best way to dynamically change the class of the list item based on the user interaction with them, and maintain the state?

Answer (score 1):

Insert an 'active' class through the server side script if the page you're on is the tab page.